postgresql pgadmin 4 insert a row in a table inserts the same row in another table with different name and similar columns
I have two tables t1, t2 with similar columns, when i insert into t1, postgresql pgadmin 4 inserts the same data into t2, how to avoid this interaction?
thanks in advance
insert into t1 (col1, col2) values (v1, v2);
the result is it insert v1, v2 in both t1 and t2

This doesn't seem likely. You are confusing something or not explaining something correctly. (a) try to reproduce this with psql please and (b) show the definitions of the two tables please.

Hard to believe, especially without any evidence. And if it would, you should report a bug at the pgAdmin project. Most likely you're looking at the wrong table, table t1 has a trigger that also inserts into t2, t2 is actually a view on t1, or some other user related issue. Besides that, two tables with the same structure usually indicate issues with the data model.

Please check if t1 is not inherited from t2.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html

Please create a [mre].

Thanks Julius table t1 is inherited from  t2 now every thing went write thanks every one specialy Julius

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
